# How to send a mail on a click?

Tags: thunderbird

I just want to send a mail automatically on clicking an icon. I want to Attach Ping and Trace Report automatically with time stamp to some of the Email Address with some text in the message body. Is it possible ? I am using thunderbird as my email client with ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up the console mailer "postfix".

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-modules
```

Depending on what you need and what mail provider you're using, you'll have to do some configuration. The process is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Install%20Postfix . If you happen to speak German there is a more user friendly article: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/postfix

Then create a shell script from the template:

```
#!/bin/bash
pingreturn=$(ping -c 1 google.com)
echo "text in email: $pingreturn" | mail -s "Some Subject" a.b@c.de
```

This will send the mail "text in email: " followed by the return of the ping command to the address "a.b@c.de" with the sucject "Some subject".

With a launcher for that script you got your one-click mail. Shoudn't be terribly hard. Might be overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

We do this by using a script and [`mutt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/mutt.1.html) (`sudo apt-get install mutt`) as command line mail client. It is one of few command line mail clients that can use attachments. Plus afaik it does not need any setting up: it uses the currently active mail setup.

As an example you could make a script with a ping and a mail with an attachment and a mailbody(with the same information) like this:

`ping www.google.nl -c 4 > {attachment}`
`ping www.google.nl -c 4 > {/dir/to/mailbody}`
`mutt {mailadress} -s {subject} -a {attachment} -c {cc} -b {bcc} < {/dir/to/mailbody}`

And the launcher, icon or a link or what ever you want this to activate it just needs to launch the script.

Comment: mutt is a bit bulky and hard to configure. but it can send attachments. If it's enough to just include the ping in the text body, then i'd not use mutt.

Comment: @con-f-use he wants tracert too and ping output could be rather long that's why I opted for mutt. But it good to have choices :-)

Comment: I meant no offence. I like mutt too, and your comment for that matter :)